# Issue decoding ajax post in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, object

I am trying to decode an array of objects that I made in javascript and sent to php however, I cant seem to decode it correctly. 
The array with an object looks like this: [image]

the php code that I am using to get the information is this:

```
$allInformation = $_POST['information'];

//this works
$user = $allInformation[count($allInformation)-2];
$num = $allInformation = [count($allInformation)-1];
//this doesnt work 
$array = var_dump(json_decode($allInformation));
```

The index of array 1 and 2 work just fine, however, I cant seem to decode index 0 which is the object. How may I go about this?

Comment: how do you sent it ? probably you need `JSON.stringify` information, and do
`json_decode($_POST['information'])`;

Comment: give more info like what is expected result what error you are getting ?

Comment: I sent it using ajax with the following format : `var data = [];` In my loop to gather my data, I use the data array to insert the following : `data[i] = {'user': username, 'date':date}`. I then pass data as is to ajax to post it.

Comment: with jQuery ? so you serialize it not as json, just var_dump($allInformation)

Comment: this is my output using `$file = json_decode($_POST['information']);
echo $file[0]["user"];`    OUTPUT:             `<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-fatal-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in ...`

Comment: What is the output of print_r($allInformation) ? is that the one you attached ?

Comment: What you post from javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it to work, the array to php which was JSON stringified  was [{"user":"user","date":"03/17/2017"},"user",134997] and i did $update = json_decode($_POST['information']); and then looped it to get user and date as obejcts i.e. $update[$i]->date . thanks all